# Aftership webhook tracking API

Tags: django, webhooks

I am developing one e-commerce app project where I have to track the order status. I use Aftership Webhook API. Webhook provides a tracking event updates to our specified webhook URL(defined in our server). I read documentation but I dont know the proper approach to test the API. and in documentation it is also not defined. Can anyone tell or suggest me how can I test or track the updates.

Answer (score 3):

To test Aftership API, first, you can follow the [API reference](https://www.aftership.com/docs/api/4/overview) to get your API key. And to tracking an order with webhook, your need to do the `POST /trackings` to `https://api.aftership.com/v4` beforehand with body like(you can add optional parameter to the request body):

```
{"tracking": {"tracking_number": "<order tracking number>"}
```

And then you can follow the [webhook documentation](https://www.aftership.com/docs/api/4/webhook) and add your webhook URL and configure the types of updates you want to get. At this point, you should be able to see the tracking update HTTP request coming into your webhook URL. Remember it will only send callback request when there is tracking status update.

Also, you can use other tracking APIs to get the status, update the tracking or delete it now.